# How does a monk jump as far as they want?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, movement, monk, dnd-3e

In the *Order of the Stick* webcomic,

> the Monk/Paladin Miko goes mad and tries to rationalize her own bad decisions.

This was back when OOTS still occasionally made jabs at the D&D 3.5 rules.  [Roy describes her behavior in strip #406 page 2 panel 10 like this](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0406.html):

> It's like she has **that monk class ability that lets you jump as far as you want**, only with her, it applies to conclusions.

What kind of broken D&D build is that a reference to?

I looked [on Wikia](https://oots.fandom.com/wiki/A_Moment_of_Truth_(406)), but all it mentions is the Slow Fall ability, which lets a monk fall as far as they want, and I suspect there might be more to this reference than that.

Update: I also looked [in the thread on the OOTS forum discussing this strip](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?32867-OOTS-406-The-Discussion-Thread&highlight=%23406).  [The only relevant post seems to be by MReav](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=1897577), which claims that this ability was something in D&D 3rd ed.

Comment: I should have looked at http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?32867-OOTS-406-The-Discussion-Thread&highlight=%23406 the forum thread about that strip before asking this question. I'd like to point to http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0176.html for a different D&D joke about jumping in OOTS. There was also something somewhere about how Titans can't jump on a table as tall as their knee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Lost Jump Mechanics

In the revision to 3.5, several skills were overhauled, Jump among them. Previously the text was:

> The maximum distance of any jump is a function of the character's height.

with different proportions depending on whether the jump was standing or running, horizontal or vertical. And the Monk got the ability to ignore this, as:

> Leap of the Clouds: At 7th level or higher, a monk's jumping distance (vertical or horizontal) is not limited according to her height.

3.5 dropped the limitation, and of course the Monk no longer needed a class ability dedicated to bypassing it, so that was dropped, too.

Order of the Stick is a 3.5 "edition" comic, but characters have been aware of previous system versions for comedic purposes before.